# MVC3 web site with Wordpress in subdirectory

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, wordpress

My hosting plan includes 1 site. I have installed a MVC3 project on that site and it is working as designed. Now I would like install a blog on the same site in a subdirectory. The blog I am using is Wordpress. Wordpress is installed to a subdirectory on the MVC3 site. When I run the 
Wordpress blog I get a .NET error page with the error:

"'System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded"

The MVC3 site runs at http://www.setlisthelper.com
I want the blog site to run at http://www.setlisthelper.com/blog

I assume MVC3 is looking for a BlogController when I go the blog directory. Is there a setting in IIS7 or MVC3 that tells it to leave the blog directory alone and not use .NET?

Answer (score 3):

try adding this to your `RegisterRoutes` function in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*blog}", new { blog = @"blog(/.*)?" });
```

You should be able to go to it with link: `http://www.setlisthelper.com/blog/index.php`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did need to do this. However, my initial issue was solved by uploading the .NET dll's to a bin folder in the blog vdir. Therefore, I have a bin directory in the root and blog subdirectory. Not sure why I need to do this. The blog dir is an Application directory so maybe that is why.

Comment: Uploading the bin folder to the virtual directory solved the problem for me too.